# How to use variable of one function to another function without declaring global variable in this case?

Tags: python

I have a function like this:

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        # session_name = request.POST['session']

        url = request.POST['hostname']

        username = request.POST['username']

        password = request.POST['password']
```

This function gets the hostname, username and password from a form and store in a respective variable. I want to use the variables url, username and password in another function:

```
def another_function():
    print url, username, password
```

What's the right way to do this? I could make upload_file return the variable and use that but I guess it can be done only with one variable.

Comment: You can return multiple variables in a function  return (url, username, password)

Answer (score 0):

well, you can add at the end of the function:

```
    return url, username, password
```

and then do this

```
    url, username, password=upload_file(request)
```

like this the first function returns all the three variables and after you can use them in the other function!

Comment: you can also do something like this: `def another_function(def upload_file(request))`

Comment: Nop, not working! I get error: I tried to do: def test():
    a = "ok"
    b = "hi"
    c = "there"
    return a, b, c  
    a, b, c = test()
    
def hello():
    print a, b, c

Comment: `def upload_file(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST':      
        # session_name = request.POST['session']  
        url = request.POST['hostname']  
        username = request.POST['username']  
        password = request.POST['password']  
    return url, username, password`  
`def another function(url, username, password):  
    print url, username, password`  
then you do this in the shell:  
`url, username, password=upload_file(request)`  
after you can use the other function:  
`another_function(url, username, password)

Comment: Can't you see edit button in your answer? Click on edit and add this to your answer.